# Calling custom class methods after collision detection, which returns a SKPhysicsBody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I figured out how to do collision detection using PhysicsBody and this method works:

```
// Method call:
projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, monster: secondBody.node as SKSpriteNode)

// Method:
func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile:SKSpriteNode, monster:SKSpriteNode!) {
    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.removeFromParent()
}
```

The method call was placed in a method that serves as the `SKPhysicsContact` receiver. It gets a pair of `SKPhysicsBody` objects passed to it, checks that they are the right type, and then calls the other method to have those objects removed.

However, I want change the Monster to have hit points.

I created a separate class called Monster, which has the following code:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class Monster : SKSpriteNode {
    var hp : Int

    override init () {
        let color = UIColor()
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "monster")
        let size = texture.size()
        hp = 5

        super.init (texture: texture, color: color, size: size)
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func subtract () {
        hp--
        println(hp)
    }
}
```

and so I want to run this code, customized for Monster:

```
projectileDidCollideWithMonster(firstBody.node as SKSpriteNode, monster: secondBody.node as Monster)

func projectileDidCollideWithMonster(projectile:SKSpriteNode, monster:Monster!) {
    projectile.removeFromParent()
    monster.subtract();
}
```

In Java, I could just cast it, such as `(Monster)secondBody.node`. I know that the secondBody is a Monster. The Monster holds reference to it's PhysicsBody, and inherits `SKSpriteNode`.

I tried this: `let theMonster = secondBody.node as Monster` but that didn't work, either.

The sprite kit physics engine seems to return PhysicsBody objects, on which I can call built-in methods like `removeFromParent()`. But I want to call my own `subtract()` method instead, which is part of Monster!

How can I trigger a custom method on an object that I received via collision detection?

Comment: I think you are assuming that the order of the colliding bodies is fixed, but the mosnter can bei either the first ir second bidy at any time

Comment: There was more code, I left it out to be succinct. The full method where the method call is located checks to make sure which one is of which type before calling the method, and if necessary, reverses them.

Comment: This code looks okay (on a quick read, at least). How exactly is it failing for you, and where?

Comment: It compiles and runs. At run time, when it detects a collision, it crashes, with the method call line highlighted. The stack says "swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
let theMonster = monster as Monster
projectile.removeFromParent()
theMonster.subtract();
```

Thanks!!